# Нужна функция для генерации 5 случайных латинских символов на PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, случайные-числа

Надеюсь не захейтите меня за возможно "простой" вопрос, хотя на прошлый "сложный" по JWT так никто и не ответил)) Не суть.

Пишу Api на ларке. Мне нужно при успешном бронировании мест генерировать в базу УНИКАЛЬНЫЙ КОД БРОНИРОВАНИЯ, состоящий из 5 латинских символов и его же потом возвращать юзеру. Уникальный код бронирования желательно в апперкейсе.

Знаю пару функций в php - rand(); uniqid(); . Первая не подходит, т.к. генерит только числа, а вторая генерит и то и другое, но по дефолту 13 символов. Исходя из задания, мне нужно ИМЕННО 5. Латинских.

В нэте только варианты с двумя этими выше упомянутыми функциями, либо с написанием собственных. Разве встроенных уже нет таких?

Ну и если нет, хотелось бы тогда увидеть компактный вариант реализации данной задачи, чтобы запомнить несложно было.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Начинающие пользователи очень часто путают понятия уникальности и случайности. В их представлении это одно и тоже. Хотя в реальности это, разумеется, не так.

Учитывая, что нужно именно уникальное значение, а так же то что длина ограничена пятью символами (то есть случайное значение ваще не вариант), у нас остатся только одно, совершенно очевидное и весьма простое решение - конвертировать обычный уникальный автоинкрементный айди из десятичной в 26-ричную систему, где базой будет латинский алфавит.

Для того чтобы сразу получить пятизначный код, просто прибавим к айди миллион

```
$code = num2alpha($id + 1000000);

function num2alpha($n) {
    $r = '';
    for ($i = 1; $n >= 0 && $i < 10; $i++) {
    $r = chr(0x41 + ($n % pow(26, $i) / pow(26, $i - 1))) . $r;
    $n -= pow(26, $i);
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но это не совсем то, что нужно. Я пишу Rest Api на Laravel, параллельно его изучая. Делаю я это по заданию WorldSkills 2020, с которым столкнулся во время участия в этом году впервые. Так вот, там УЖЕ готовый дамп базы, в котором в таблице с бронированием есть колонка CODE, которая НЕ ИМЕЕТ автоинкремент и в которой задан тип varchar(5). Любые изменения в данную базу данных - минус балл к оценке. Вероятно вы правы, и я не до конца понимаю разницу уникальности и случайности. Но вариант от пользователя выше все же больше подходит под мою задачу.

Comment: Но я конечно же, благодарен вам за помощь и я обязательно учту данный вариант при разработке в будущем! Спасибо! Вот только ставить минусы всем и везде было совсем не обязательно, весьма неприятно.

Comment: колонка code и не может иметь автоинкремент, поскольку такая колонка в таблице может быть только одна. И у меня ясно написано, что код строится от id. Но если уж костылить со случайным кодом, то хотя бы ясно что надо его генерить в цикле, проверяя на уникальность?

Comment: `колонка CODE, которая НЕ ИМЕЕТ автоинкремент` - получаем MAX(CODE), который из строки переводим в число, затем +1, затем `num2alpha`. Это решит вашу проблему. Минус этого решения - если есть код "ZZZZZ", новый номер не получим, хотя, допустим, свободен AAAAA. Но лучше смотрите вашу базу и условия задачи, может быть там все последовательно. Без знания всех условий задачи, написать подходящее решение сложно. Дополните вопрос всеми условиями.

Comment: PS. Есть еще один вариант, по принципу построения [первичного ключа в Mongo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php). Идея такая: первые 3 символа - закодированное значение даты 26^3 = 17576 = можно закодировать интервал 48 лет. Следующие 2 байта - последовательный номер 26^2 = 676 броней в день. Если удовлетворяет условиям - используйте это решение. Ну и [вот еще решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4382586/9435985), вам нужно его доработать чтобы оно работало со строками, а не числами. А как переводить число в строку, показано в ответе выше, нужно это портировать в SQL

Answer (score 0):

Встроенной функции нет!
Возможно вам поможет это

```
function generator_kods() {
$chars = 'abdefhiknrstyzABDEFGHKNQRSTYZ';
$string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, 30) - 1, 1);
return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function getCode()
{
   $random = Str::random(5);
   return Str::upper($random);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Возвращаемое значение не будет уникальным.